# perl regex: stucked with regex capture

Tags: regex, perl, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to extract the time taken in a process from a log.

For example the log contains(the relevant lines):

```
Time for search copy=15 s.
Time for content copy=45 s.
Time for unzip reply=20 s.
```

The above lines are flanked with many others lines in the log which are not required. There are several kind of jobs which generates such logs(log name is process.out) so we have a Job_name as as identifier for each job.
I am using hash to read the logs for a particular job. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my %Log_name = ();
my %File_name = ();
my %filetoread = ();
my %filetoreadStrings = ();
my @ftr      = ();
my @reply    = ();
my @content  = ();
my @search   = ();
my %Reply    = ();
my %Search   = ();
my %Content = ();
my $curr_dir=`pwd`;
chop($curr_dir);

my $Log_name = "ABC-DEF";
my $File_name=<$curr_dir/p*.out>;
my $filetoread = basename ($File_name);
my $filetoreadStrings=`strings $filetoread  | egrep "(Time for)"`;
@ftr = split('\n', $filetoreadStrings);
chomp (@ftr);


for (my $count = 0; $count < 6; $count++)    #The lines are repeated 6 times except for the "search copy" line which is repeated twice
{
 $reply[$count] = (grep /Time for unzip reply/, @ftr)[$count];
 $content[$count] = (grep /Time for content copy/, @ftr)[$count];
 $search[$count] = (grep /Time for search copy/, @ftr)[$count];
 if (defined $reply[$count]) 
 {
 ($Reply{$Log_name})  = $reply[$count] =~ /Time for unzip reply=(\d+) s./;

 printf "$Reply{$Log_name}\n";
 }
  if (defined $content[$count]) {
 ($Content{$Log_name})=$content[$count]=~/Time for content copy=(\d+) s./;

 printf "$Content{$Log_name}\n";
  }
  if (defined $search[$count]) {
   ($Search{$Log_name})  = $search[$count] =~ /Time for search copy=(\d+) s./;

   printf "$Search{$Log_name}\n";
  }

 }
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at new_try_loop.pl line 46.
```

The above output corresponds to each of the printf statements. I actually need to add up these time values to calculate the total time and this I've not shown in the code since the important thing is to get the "time" first.

What needs to be done here? Let me know if any other info is required.

Initially, I was not using the for loop and this code was working. e.g.,

```
$reply1 = (grep /Time for unzip reply/, @ftr)[0];
$Reply1{$Log_name})  = $reply1 =~ /Time for unzip reply=(\d+) s./;
$reply2 = (grep /Time for unzip reply/, @ftr)[1];
$Reply2{$Log_name})  = $reply1 =~ /Time for unzip reply=(\d+) s./;
$reply3 = (grep /Time for unzip reply/, @ftr)[2];
$Reply3{$Log_name})  = $reply1 =~ /Time for unzip reply=(\d+) s./;
.......... and so on
```

In the similar way I was storing the value in $Content{$Log_name} and $Search{$Log_name}. I was getting the regex captured in these variables and later adding them up. I'm using for loop to optimize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sections like this

```
if (defined $reply[$count]) 
 {
 ($Reply{$Log_name})  = $reply[$count] =~ /Time for unzip reply=(\d+) s./;

 printf "$Reply{$Log_name}\n";
 }
```

Become

```
if (defined $reply[$count] && ($reply[$count] =~ /Time for unzip reply=(\d+) s./) ) 
 {
 ($Reply{$Log_name})  = $1
 print "$1\n";
 }
```

I assume some of your data matches `/Time for unzip reply/` but not `/Time for unzip reply=(\d+) s./`

Comment: Thank you! This is working as per my requirement, I used your code after making few modifications. And also your assumption was correct :).